# Popup is not coming to ask permission to access camera in iOS 12

Tags: ios, ios12

As per the apple standard, we need to ask permission to access user camera. so I have successfully integrated camera and it is working fine in iOS 11. but currently, I am testing camera feature and found that if user one time allowed camera access, The same app will not ask for permission even after fresh installed(from app store).

so my question is, is it behavious changed in iOS 12 or we need to do some setup to asked permission every time when user try to install fresh App?

Thanks

Comment: related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52622481/ios-12-camera-working-without-camera-permission-dialog-box

Comment: @Scriptable, unfortunately it's look similar question.

Comment: I have the same problem with iOS 12, did you fix it?

Comment: @CGR, I think in iOS 12, Apple changed behavior. If you granted permission at once they are not asking for permission second time everafter fresh installed. It will stored at OS level may be with bundle identifier.

Comment: @JatinPatel Yes, I am also facing the same issue, my app got rejected due to accessing privacy sensitive data and they said i did not included NSCameraUsageDescription in plist. But it was there in the project, and it is not popping up the default permission alert.

Comment: @JatinPatel Did you fix it?. Having same problem with IOS 12

Comment: @Vikky, still not fixed it. even though apple will approved my app.

Comment: @JatinPatel I can't find anywhere that its a behaviour, but now when I checked in IOS 10 still the same behaviour continues.

Comment: @Vikky, for iOS 10, It is working fine in my case.

Comment: @JatinPatel Did you find the solution? I still have the same bug only in iOS 12.1

Answer (score 1):

**iOS 12.1 / Swift 4.2**

Every time the user taps on the Camera button in your app, you call this code. It firstly asks for permissions, and if the settings are still there from the past installs, UIAlertController pops up, allowing the user to open the Settings app on the device, and change camera permission settings.

OnCameraOpenButtonTap()

```
if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
   checkCameraAccess(isAllowed: {
            if $0 {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.presentCamera()
                }
            } else {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.presentCameraSettings()
            }
        }
    })
}

func checkCameraAccess(isAllowed: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    switch AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .video) {
    case .denied:
        isAllowed(false)
    case .restricted:
        isAllowed(false)
    case .authorized:
        isAllowed(true)
    case .notDetermined:
        AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video) { isAllowed($0) }
    }
}

private func presentCamera() {
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
    present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

private func presentCameraSettings() {
    let alert = UIAlertController.init(title: "allowCameraTitle", message: "allowCameraMessage", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { (_) in
    }))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Settings", style: .default, handler: { (_) in
        UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }))

    present(alert, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: for me, camera option was not there, in my app setting